# Visual Studio 2012 application settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, application-settings

I have read the [tutorial on application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a65txexh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and I don't understand a bit. All I know is that I've created a `.settings` file using the designer, assigned values to it, and `Properties.Settings.Default` doesn't let me access them because it says they don't exist (what the tutorial is saying is that if you create an entry called `Foo`, then you can access it with Properties.Settings.Default.Foo, which, as I said, doesn't work). Can someone please explain to me how to work with .settings files and access the settings themselves?

[image: My settings file]

Comment: Please show your code and/or a screenshot of your Application Settings screen.

Comment: There isn't any code apart from the default one generated by VS and me trying to access the settings. As for the screenshot, coming right up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but then I used only `Settings.Default` instead of `Properties.Settings.Default`, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Please, set select Access Modifier as `internal` and I believe it will help.